# Linux shared library loading and sharing the code with other process

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Suppose I have a shared library `a.so` which is loaded for the first time by my executable. My understanding is that to the middle of VMA, the shared library text sections are mapped. I have two questions;

(1) Is the ld.so going to load this shared memory text section pages to the physical memory and then maps to the VMA of that process?

(2) Suppose a second executable is started which uses the same shared library `a.so`. Is ld.so going to identify that this shared library is already loaded to the physical memory? How does it work to understand that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be precise, it's not `ld.so`'s job to reserve physical memory or to manage or choose the mapping between virtual and physical memory, it's the kernel's job. When `ld.so` loads a shared library, it does so through the `mmap` syscall, and the kernel allocates the needed physical memory<sup>(1)</sup> and creates a virtual mapping between the library file and the physical memory. What is then returned by `mmap` is the virtual base address of the mapped library, which will then be used by the dynamic loader as a base to service calls to functions of that library.

> Is `ld.so` going to identify that this shared library is already loaded to the physical memory? How does it work to understand that?

It's not `ld.so`, but the kernel that is going to identify this. It's a complicated process, but to make it simple, the kernel keeps track of which file is mapped where, and can detect when a request is made to map an already mapped file again, avoiding physical memory allocation if possible.

If the same file (i.e. a file with the same path) is mapped multiple times, the kernel will look at the existing mappings, and *if possible* it will reuse the same physical pages to avoid wasting memory. So ideally, if a shared library is loaded multiple times, it could be physically allocated only once.

In practice it's not that simple though. Since memory can also be written to, this "sharing" of physical pages can obviously only occur if the page that needs to be shared is unchanged from the original content of the file (otherwise different processes mapping the same file or library would interfere with each other). This is basically always true for code sections (`.text`) since they are usually read-only, and for other similar sections (like read-only data). It can also happen for RW sections if they are not modified<sup>(2)</sup>. So in short, the `.text` segments of already loaded libraries are usually only allocated into physical memory once.

---

(1) Actually, the kernel creates the mapping first, and then only allocates physical memory if the process tries to read or write to it through the mapping. This prevents wasting memory when it's not needed.

(2) This technique of sharing physical memory is managed through a [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) mechanism where the kernel initially maps "clean" pages and marks them as "dirty" when they are written to, duplicating them as needed.

Comment: ,@Employed Russian - This manner of  sharing of .text segments in physical memory is same if I load an a.out multiple times?

Comment: @FrancM It's same for every single file in the system, not only executables. For executables `.text` segments are usually read only and therefore a good example of this.

Answer (score 4):

Linux shared libraries are normally position independent (so are executables because of address space randomization). Position independent code uses GOT and PLT relocation mechanisms to locate all symbols with external linkage at run-time.

When dynamic linker `ld.so` loads a position independent executable or shared library, only GOT and PLT segments must be modified in process memory, `.text` segment with code is mapped into process memory as read-only. When another process loads the same executable or shared library it ends up mapping the same page frames where `.text` segment is already loaded by other processes, but not GOT and PLT which are specific to a process address space layout.

`ld.so` essentially does `mmap(NULL, text_segment_len, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, elf_file_fd, text_segment_offset)` when loading an ELF file. That populates the kernel [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (on the first access), so that another process that makes this call maps the page frames already present in the page cache.

See [Position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Technical_details) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. So when the second process is loaded, is that ```ld.so``` or the ```kernel``` identifies that the ```.text``` section of ```a.so``` is already available in the physical memory?

Comment: @FrancM Added `mmap` note for you.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks for your comment, replaced "section" with "segment".

Comment: But `.text` is not a segment. It is a *section* located in a `LOAD` type segment.

Comment: Does `dlmopen` still follow this rule? Will `dlmopen` cause multiple physical memory copies of a read-only segment?

Comment: what about non-pie executables? are they being loaded with `.text` shared among different processes as well? I think pie shouldn't affect `.text` sharing, it only makes GOT and PLT segments different.

Comment: @RayEldath I am not familiar with non-pie executables.